# HTML - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a short question. I have no idea why this code isn't working, I tried different options to get my localhost.

I get this everytime I'm trying to load my localhost:

> Refused to load the font 'data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAJs0ABMAAAABTVgAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABGRlRNAAABqAAAABwAAAAcaikRNkdERUYAAAHEAAAALQAAADIDDwH7R1BPUwAAAfQAABgwAABX1Oqq9j9HU1VCAAAaJAAAAXQAAALKqyaj7U9TLzIAABuYAAAAVgAAAGCRWm0zY21hcAAAG/AAAAGQAAAB6jHNvzdjdnQgAAAdgAAAAEYAAABGFNMQDmZwZ20AAB3IAAABsQAAAmVTtC+nZ2FzcAAAH3wAAAAIAAAACAAAABBnbHlmAAAfhAAAcrwAAN3gTmoUWWhlYWQAAJJAAAAAMQAAADYJ67FUaGhlYQAAknQAAAAeAAAAJA0SBixobXR4AACSlAAAAkgAAAOuDPhKF2xvY2EAAJTcAAABzAAAAdq5toTebWF4cAAAlqgAAAAgAAAAIAIJAfRuYW1...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' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
>
> session.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a
>   status of 404 (Not Found)

Here is my code:

```js
import express    = require ("express");      
import { Request, Response } from "express";  
import session = require('express-session');
let router = express();
router.listen(8080, "localhost", function () {
  console.log("  Aufruf: http://localhost:8080/../../session.html");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sessions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/sessions/sessionServer.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/sessions/session.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

</head>
```

the structure is:

Folder Sessions:

1. different folders

   2. ...
   3. sessions

   3.1 folders

   3.2 ..

   3.3 session.html

Comment: I have a silly question for you. What is your server and how do you create and run it? Thanks

Comment: i create my owm server with the code from above (I get this code from my professor). We run it with node.js

Comment: my style.css is at the moment empty, I have only five buttons on my website and those I styled directly in the HTML File

Comment: @zack6849 I think it is font awesome which is loaded like that

Comment: so what should or could i do? I have no css and i have no idea why I can't see my simple html page with only a few buttons on it ..